# How Can I run Mule runtime engine Running

Tags: java, mule, mulesoft, mule-component, mule4

Hi everyone I am trying to start mule runtime engine from [open source](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule) and trying to run a simple hello word application in it.
I followed same steps from [CONTRIBUTING Guide](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md). But I am getting some errors. Detailed log is below.
When I just download code and run it has some dependencies missing too.
If someone can just provide me a proper guide link it will also work for.

Application

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="d6132ed6-b549-4a5a-ab30-b0006362476b" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <flow name="hello-worldFlow" doc:id="fb709ee4-0263-492c-92e3-ba5bb6287cd7" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="b4f5d981-3869-46e4-879b-2ba9e8e1c2b7" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/helloWorld"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="d254b372-8ea9-4b59-bb07-04cc2bf715a5" message="#[attributes.requestPath]"/>
        <set-payload value="Hello World!" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="c04ac342-40dd-48ec-bf80-206d3aaa77e3" mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Error

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy artifact 'hello-world-2.1.4-mule-application-example',      +
+ org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentInitException:               +
+ NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type                    +
+ 'org.mule.runtime.api.scheduler.SchedulerService' available: expected at     +
+ least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:  +
+ {}                                                                           +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Logs

```
ERROR 2021-06-28 15:14:42,543 [main] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer: Failed to deploy artifact [hello-world-2.1.4-mule-application-example]
org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifact [hello-world-2.1.4-mule-application-example]
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentInitException: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.mule.runtime.api.scheduler.SchedulerService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentInitException: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.mule.runtime.api.scheduler.SchedulerService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name '_muleMetadataService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '_metadataCacheManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'objectStoreManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '_muleObjectStoreManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSchedulerService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.mule.runtime.api.scheduler.SchedulerService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Error creating bean with name '_muleMetadataService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '_metadataCacheManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'objectStoreManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '_muleObjectStoreManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSchedulerService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.mule.runtime.api.scheduler.SchedulerService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '_muleMetadataService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '_metadataCacheManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'objectStoreManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '_muleObjectStoreManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSchedulerService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.mule.runtime.api.scheduler.SchedulerService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.ObjectProviderAwareBeanFactory.getBean(ObjectProviderAwareBeanFactory.java:78) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:101) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:94) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:111) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:73) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:1) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:132) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:61) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.context.DefaultMuleContext.initialise(DefaultMuleContext.java:321) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:177) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:60) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.ArtifactContextBuilder.lambda$2(ArtifactContextBuilder.java:485) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:224) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:967) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:885) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.ArtifactContextBuilder.build(ArtifactContextBuilder.java:397) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.application.DefaultMuleApplication.doInit(DefaultMuleApplication.java:235) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:204) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:265) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:924) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:862) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.DeployableArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(DeployableArtifactWrapper.java:146) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.DeployableArtifactWrapper.init(DeployableArtifactWrapper.java:89) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArtifactDeployer.doInit(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:141) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:60) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:466) [classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:237) [classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:569) [classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:1) [classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:251) [classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.run(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:321) [classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:151) [classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:156) [classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:256) [classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.launcher.MuleContainer.main(MuleContainer.java:125) [classes/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '_metadataCacheManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'objectStoreManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '_muleObjectStoreManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSchedulerService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.mule.runtime.api.scheduler.SchedulerService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.ObjectProviderAwareBeanFactory.getBean(ObjectProviderAwareBeanFactory.java:78) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.ObjectProviderAwareBeanFactory.getBean(ObjectProviderAwareBeanFactory.java:78) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:101) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:94) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:111) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:73) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:1) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:132) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:61) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.context.DefaultMuleContext.initialise(DefaultMuleContext.java:321) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:177) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:60) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.ArtifactContextBuilder.lambda$2(ArtifactContextBuilder.java:485) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:224) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:967) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:885) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.ArtifactContextBuilder.build(ArtifactContextBuilder.java:397) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.application.DefaultMuleApplication.doInit(DefaultMuleApplication.java:235) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:204) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:265) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:924) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:862) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.DeployableArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(DeployableArtifactWrapper.java:146) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.DeployableArtifactWrapper.init(DeployableArtifactWrapper.java:89) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArtifactDeployer.doInit(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:141) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:60) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:466) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:237) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:569) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:1) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:251) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.run(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:321) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:151) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:156) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:256) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.launcher.MuleContainer.main(MuleContainer.java:125) ~[classes/:?]
```

Thank you

Comment: You should not link the question to external files. Please add the log text to the question. Also add the XML text of the application and what dependencies it has, if any, as source text in the question. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question and how to use properly links in Stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Hi @aled I linked file because error text was too big to write here. I hope edited question will provide clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the application is OK but the Mule runtime you built from sources is missing the [scheduler service](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-scheduler-service). Maybe the instructions are just mentioning how to build the core runtime. Other services maybe missing too, like the HTTP service.

Comment: Yes you are right. is there any guide which will help me to solve this problem ? Thank you for your support and time.

Comment: I debug the code and found this [Line](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/9b0daa087cec5f4be4cce828b90e2bfc1dba7af2/modules/spring-config/src/main/java/org/mule/runtime/config/internal/ObjectProviderAwareBeanFactory.java#L78) is throwing error. where name is `"_muleMetadataService"`. what should I do now ?

Comment: I don't know if there is a documented way to build a distribution with the required services.

Comment: Is there any other person or channel where I can get this help ?